# Given a Baire one function, is it true that its restriction to special subset continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, ordinals

**Background**: Let $X$ be a Polish space, that is, a separable completely metrizable topological space.
Assume that $F$ is a closed subset of $X.$
Recall that a function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is called **Baire-1** if it is a pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions. 
For any $\varepsilon>0$ and $x\in X,$ recall that **oscillation** of $f$ is defined by 
$$\omega(f,x,F) = \inf_{\delta>0}\sup_{y,z\in B(x,\delta)\cap F}|f(y)-f(z)|$$
where $B(x,\delta) = \{u\in X: d(u,x)<\delta\}.$
Denote 
$$D^0(f,\varepsilon,F) = F,$$
$$D^1(f,\varepsilon,F) = \{x\in F: \omega(f,x,F)\geq \varepsilon \}.$$
Clearly $D^1(f,\varepsilon,F)$ is a close subset of $X.$

...................................................................................................................................................................

[Denny and his co-authors](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~matlhh/preprints/54%20Ordinal%20ranks.pdf) proved the following lemma.

> **Lemma** **2.2**: Suppose that $F$ is a closed subset of $X$ and that $f$ is a Baire class $1$ function on $X.$
>   For any $\varepsilon>0,$ there exists a continuous function $g:F\setminus D^1(f,\varepsilon,F)\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)-g(x)|<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in F\setminus D^1(f,\varepsilon,F).$

My question is, can we make the bound $|f(x)-g(x)|$ tight? 
More precisely,

> **Question**: Suppose that $F$ is a closed subset of $X$ and that $f$ is a Baire class $1$ function on $X.$
>   For any $\varepsilon>0,$ does there exist a continuous function $g:F\setminus D^1(f,\varepsilon,F)\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_{|F}=g$ on $x\in F\setminus D^1(f,\varepsilon,F)?$

Another interpretation of my question is that given any Baire-1 function, is it true that the restriction of $f$ to $F\setminus D^1(f,\varepsilon,F)$ continuous for all closed subsets?

Comment: It seems that you could procure a uniformly Cauchy sequence $\{g_n\}$ of continuous functions on $F-D^1(f,\epsilon, F)$ from their lemma. And a uniformly Cauchy sequence of continuous functions approaches a unique continuous function.

Comment: Note that $\omega(f,x,F)$ is $0$ iff $f$ is continuous at $x$. So if you have $x \in F$, $\delta>0$ such that $]x-\delta,x+\delta[ \cap D^1(f,\varepsilon,F)=\varnothing$ and $\omega(f,x,F) \in ]0,\varepsilon[$, then $f$ won't be continuous on $]x-\delta,x+\delta[-D^1(f,\varepsilon,F)$. Maybe we can find some additional conditions on $D^1(f,\varepsilon,F)$ for it to be true

Comment: @charMD I agree

Comment: Another remark;: if your proposotion were true, you would be claiming that if $f$ is a bounded Baire $1$ function, then $f$ is continuous (with $\varepsilon=1+2\cdot \sup\limits_{x\in f}|f(x)|$, $D^1(f,\varepsilon,F)=\varnothing$). And this is clearly false.

Comment: Is it possible to provide a concrete example to demonstrate that the statement is false?